# C++ gtk update textview when the signal is always on, how do that?

Tags: c++, multithreading, gtk, signals

I have a signal on_btn_clicked(GtkButton*bt),it long working. In signal i using gtk_text_buffer_insert().
But text in gtktextview update only when the signal end. I need update textview when working the signal. How can i solve this question?
I am reading about g_timeout_add, g_idle_add, but i dont understand how solve it)).

```
#include <gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkx.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <glib-2.0/glib.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

#include "../inc/GtkTextBufferManager.hpp"

using namespace std::chrono_literals; // ns, us, ms, s, h, etc.
using std::chrono::system_clock;




class MyGtk{
private:
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkBuilder *builder;
  GtkWidget *textView;
  GtkWidget *btPlay;
  GtkTextBufferManager*manager;
public:
  MyGtk(int argc,char*argv[]){
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv); // init gtk
    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file("./test.glade");
    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "windowMain"));
    
    btPlay = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "btPlay"));
    manager=new GtkTextBufferManager(GTK_TEXT_BUFFER(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "textbuffer1")),10);
    textView=GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "textView"));

    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);
    
    gtk_widget_show(window);
    printf("Window ready!\n");
  }
  GtkTextBufferManager*getManager(){
    return manager;
  }
};
MyGtk*pGtk;  

extern "C"{

int main(int argc,char*argv[]){   
    
    MyGtk gtk(argc,argv);
    pGtk=&gtk;
    gtk_main();
  return 0;    
}
void on_textbuffer1_changed(GtkWidget*w){
  g_print("on_textbuffer1_changed\n");
}
void on_btPlay_clicked(GtkWidget*w){
  g_print("on_btPlay_clicked\n");
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    //work with files,Com port,CNC (long time signal)
    sleep(1);
    //change textbuff, but it update only when end signal
    pGtk->getManager()->addGStringToTextBuffer("SomeString\n");
  }
}

}
```

GtkTextBufferManager.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib-2.0/glib.h>

class GtkTextBufferManager{
    private:
    GtkTextBuffer*buff;
    GtkTextIter*startIter; 
    GtkTextIter*endIter;
    gint max;
    gint counter;
    public:
    GtkTextBufferManager(GtkTextBuffer*b,gint m):
        buff(b),max(m){
            this->counter=0;
            this->startIter=new GtkTextIter();
            this->endIter=new GtkTextIter();
    }
    GtkTextBuffer*getTextBuffer(){
        return buff;
    }
    void setTextBuffer(GtkTextBuffer*buff){
        this->buff=buff;
    }
    GtkTextIter*getStartTextIter(){
        return startIter;
    }
    GtkTextIter*getEndTextIter(){
        return endIter;
    }
    void addGStringToTextBuffer(const gchar*str){
        if(counter<max){
            gtk_text_buffer_get_start_iter(buff,startIter);
            gtk_text_buffer_insert(buff,startIter,str,-1);
            counter++;
        }else{
            //paste text
            gtk_text_buffer_get_start_iter(buff,startIter);
            gtk_text_buffer_insert(buff,startIter,str,-1);
            //delete text
            gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_line(buff,startIter,counter);
            gtk_text_buffer_get_end_iter(buff,endIter);
            gtk_text_buffer_delete(buff,startIter,endIter);
        }
    }

    ~GtkTextBufferManager(){
        if(startIter!=nullptr)
            delete startIter;
        if(endIter!=nullptr)
            delete endIter;
    }
};
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I was add code.